# Cookie file wont pass to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a problem on my page. I am trying to pass a JSON cookie to another page but after submitting and redirecting to other page then get the cookie. It seems that the page doesn't fetch the cookie from the previous page.

I tried to go back to my previous page and check my cookie if it is remove or replaced but after checking the cookie is still there.

I am using this plugin on my website:
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Here is the cookie I am trying to send:

```
Cookies.set("make_enquiry_data", { 
                            "Full Name":                $('#FullName').val(), 
                            "Email Address":            $('#EmailAddress').val(), 
                            "State":                    $('#BillingState').val(),
                            "Country":                  $('#BillingCountry').val(),
                            "Mobile Number":            $('#Cellphone').val(),
                            "Post Code":                $('#BillingZip').val(),
                            "Enquiry":                  $('#CAT_Custom_387456').val(),
                            "Enquire Now As":           $('input[name=CAT_Custom_387457]').serializeArray(),
                            "Make/Model":               $('#CAT_Custom_387458').val(),
                            "Year":                     $('#CAT_Custom_387459').val(),
                            "Kms":                      $('#CAT_Custom_387460').val()
                        });

Cookies.set("test_variable", "test me!!!");
```

And on the next page I am viewing my cookie using this code:

```
Cookies.get();
```

But unfortunately the cookie I want is not existed on the latest page.

Comment: Cookies can only store text, not objects. First convert the JS object into JSON.

Comment: @BenM Ok thanks for the info. But on my other pages and form it is working w/o any issues. It's just this page. :( But I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @BenM I tried to display the cookie on the current page and it is showing.
`make_enquiry_data
:
"{"Full Name":"CBO Test","Email Address":"test@email.me","Country":"AU","Mobile Number":"1300660285","Post Code":"2000","Enquiry":"test","Enquire Now As":[{"name":"CAT_Custom_387457","value":"Trade In"}],"Make/Model":"test model","Year":"2001","Kms":"12"}"`

Comment: So it's working?

Comment: What paths are your pages located under? You might need to specify what path the cookie is considered valid for when setting it.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can only store text, not objects. You first need to encode the object as JSON (by using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)):

```
Cookies.set("make_enquiry_data", JSON.stringify({ 
  "Full Name":      $('#FullName').val(), 
  "Email Address":  $('#EmailAddress').val(), 
  "State":          $('#BillingState').val(),
  "Country":        $('#BillingCountry').val(),
  "Mobile Number":  $('#Cellphone').val(),
  "Post Code":      $('#BillingZip').val(),
  "Enquiry":        $('#CAT_Custom_387456').val(),
  "Enquire Now As": $('input[name=CAT_Custom_387457]').serializeArray(),
  "Make/Model":     $('#CAT_Custom_387458').val(),
  "Year":           $('#CAT_Custom_387459').val(),
  "Kms":            $('#CAT_Custom_387460').val()
}));
```

Then in order to get your object back when retrieving the cookie's value, use `JSON.parse()`:

```
JSON.parse( Cookies.get('make_enquiry_data') );
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the illustration. I will try that approach and hopefully it work. :)

Comment: Ok it still same effect. I am trying also to get a cookie that has a single value but still they are both undefined. :(

Comment: But I thought you said in the comments it was working?

Comment: Yes it is working and saving on the initial page but after redirecting to the other page my set cookie wont pass. It says undefined. :(

Comment: Ok I tried to create a new cookie on my current page then I tried to access it on the initial page and it is undefined.  They are vice versa w/ each other/ :(

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use something like this, to get a particular cookie,

Cookies.get('thatcookie');